Filling only a part of SwiftUI with background color
I am trying to design a video trimmer view in SwiftUI as follows. This result is this. My question is whether I can have the middle part (i.e. everything except 20 points on the left and right and 5 points up and down) transparent so that I can show thumbnails behind them (perhaps by having a custom clip shape)?

  var body: some View {
    HStack(spacing: 10) {
        Image(systemName: "chevron.compact.left")
            .frame(height:70)
        
        Spacer()
        
        Image(systemName: "chevron.compact.right")
    }
    .foregroundColor(.black)
    .font(.title3.weight(.semibold))
    .padding(.horizontal, 7)
    .padding(.vertical, 3)
    .background(.yellow)
    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 7))
    .frame(width: 300)
    .onGeometryChange(for: CGFloat.self) { proxy in
        proxy.size.width
    } action: { width in
        print("width = \(width)")
    }

}


Instead of background and then clipShape, use background(_:in:fillStyle:). This allows you to specify a Shape in which you want the background color to fill.
You can write a Shape like  this:
struct VideoTrimmerBackgroundShape: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 7)
            .path(in: rect)
            .subtracting(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 7)
                    .path(in: rect.insetBy(dx: 20, dy: 5))
            )
    }
}

I am simply subtracting the path created by an insetted rounded rectangle from a non-insetted one.
Then
.background(.yellow, in: VideoTrimmerBackgroundShape())
// you don't need clipShape anymore!


subtracting is available since iOS 17. If you need to support a lower version, you can just add the smaller rounded rectangle as a subpath, but use even-odd filling.
struct VideoTrimmerBackgroundShape: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var p = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 7)
            .path(in: rect)
        p.addPath(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 7)
                .path(in: rect.insetBy(dx: 20, dy: 5))
        )
        return p
    }
}

.background(.yellow, in: VideoTrimmerBackgroundShape(), fillStyle: .init(eoFill: true))


That's an interesting solution and it works. I modified VideoTrimmerBackgroundShape to take arguments dx and dy. Ideally I would like to compute dx as twice the width of chevron image so that the chevrons are centered. Is it easy to modify this code to fulfill this need (although I understand this is in addition to the requirements mentioned in my question).

Another way to cut out part of the background is to use an overlay with .blendMode(.destinationOut). It is also necessary to apply .compositingGroup() to the result, to prevent the blend mode burning into deeper layers.
Replace these modifiers:
.background(.yellow)
.clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 7))

with:
.background {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 7)
        .fill(.yellow)
        .overlay {
            Rectangle()
                .padding(.vertical, 5)
                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                .blendMode(.destinationOut)
        }
        .compositingGroup()
}



You mentioned in a comment to the answer you already accepted that you would like the chevrons to look centered. Since you are applying padding of 7 at the sides, this means applying padding (or spacing) of 7 on the inner side too.
One way to achieve this is would be to move the chevrons into the overlay. Then in fact the whole view can be simplified:
var body: some View {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 7)
        .fill(.yellow)
        .frame(width: 300, height: 76)
        .overlay {
            HStack(spacing: 7) {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.compact.left")
                Rectangle()
                    .padding(.vertical, 5)
                    .blendMode(.destinationOut)
                Image(systemName: "chevron.compact.right")
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 7)
            .font(.title3.weight(.semibold))
            .foregroundStyle(.black)
        }
        .compositingGroup()
}



EDIT In this particular case, you are filling with a solid color and the middle part is a square rectangle. This means, it would be possible to build the view with just basic techniques - there is no need to use blend mode, nor custom shapes.

Use an HStack as the base view, as you were doing already.
Either fix the size of the HStack, or apply padding to constrain its size within the space available.
Make the images full height within the HStack and apply padding as required.
Give the images a yellow background.
Instead of filling the background of the HStack, stroke its border with a line of suitable thickness.
The Spacer inside the HStack then provides the "hole" automatically.

To give the rounded corners, you could use a rounded rectangle for the stroke. However, this would mean tweaking the padding of the images, so that their square corners do not show through. Alternatively, use a rectangular border and then apply a clip shape, as you were doing originally:
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Image(systemName: "chevron.compact.left")
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
            .padding(.horizontal, 7)
            .background(.yellow)
        Spacer()
        Image(systemName: "chevron.compact.right")
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
            .padding(.horizontal, 7)
            .background(.yellow)
    }
    .font(.title3.weight(.semibold))
    .foregroundStyle(.black)
    .frame(width: 300, height: 76)
    .border(.yellow, width: 5)
    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 7))
}


Interesting approach. Been playing with this code, looks good.

@DeepakSharma Answer updated with an even simpler alternative

I wish I could give one more upvote!

Your suggestions are good but I am having some trouble with it when trimming using Drag Gesture. Will post a new question soon.

Here is the link to new question.
